# oracle equivalent of mysql ifnull (no case, no if)

Tags: mysql, oracle, case, ifnull

I am looking for a quick way to do

```
SELECT IFNULL(columna, columnb) FROM mytable
```

(I have dozens of columns and don't want to write a case for each of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the standard `COALESCE` keyword, which allows you to pass it multiple parameters:

```
SELECT COALESCE(columna, columnb, ..., columnz) FROM mytable
```

[COALESCE keyword documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm)

Comment: just found out about it too. And it seems a better option (standard SQL)

Answer (score 2):

just found out:

```
SELECT nvl(columna, columnb) FROM mytable
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm