# PLSQL Block, is it poossible to Ifnull this statement?

Tags: plsql

I have a PL/SQL block that queries from an empty table. I was wondering is there any way to convert a blank result into 0? or at least us the ifnull function to this query?

Here is the code

```
declare 
p_entity_id varchar2(14) := 10100033904;
date_format varchar2(10) := 'MM/DD/YYYY';
v_mapcount integer;
v_compcount integer;
v_qa_comp_date varchar2(12) := 'MM/DD/YYYY';


begin 

SELECT SUM(total),SUM(complete),TO_CHAR(MAX(compDate),date_format) INTO v_mapCount,v_CompCount,v_qa_comp_date  FROM
(
SELECT COUNT(barcode) as total, SUM(DECODE(qa_comp,NULL,0,1)) complete ,MAX(qa_comp) compDate  from bbsp_boundary  WHERE upper(cycle1) = 'Y' AND  entity_id = p_entity_id AND DELETED_DATE IS NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(barcode) as total, SUM(DECODE(qa_comp,NULL,0,1)) complete ,MAX(qa_comp) compDate  from bbsp_feature WHERE upper(cycle1) = 'Y' AND  entity_id = p_entity_id AND DELETED_DATE IS NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(barcode) as total, SUM(DECODE(qa_comp,NULL,0,1)) complete ,MAX(qa_comp) compDate  from bbsp_ADDRESS WHERE upper(cycle1) = 'Y' AND  entity_id = p_entity_id AND DELETED_DATE IS NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(barcode) as total, SUM(DECODE(qa_comp,NULL,0,1)) complete ,MAX(qa_comp) compDate from bbsp_CORRECTION WHERE upper(cycle1) = 'Y' AND  entity_id = p_entity_id AND DELETED_DATE IS NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(barcode) as total, SUM(DECODE(qa_comp,NULL,0,1)) complete ,MAX(qa_comp) compDate  from bbsp_point_landmark WHERE upper(cycle1) = 'Y' AND  entity_id = p_entity_id AND DELETED_DATE IS NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(barcode) as total, SUM(DECODE(qa_comp,NULL,0,1)) complete ,MAX(qa_comp) compDate  from bbsp_area_landmark WHERE upper(cycle1) = 'Y' AND  entity_id = p_entity_id AND DELETED_DATE IS NULL
) ;

end;
```

Comment: which value in particular are you talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle equivalent of mysql ifnull (no case, no if)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409990/oracle-equivalent-of-mysql-ifnull-no-case-no-if)

Comment: if I can NVL() that whole statement, how would I do that ?

Comment: the `SELECT` statement has two columns, so what do you mean with NVL() that?

Answer (score 1):

If all of your tables are empty, then no row is returned, hence there is no count to return. You can reset those variables to zero with an `if .. then ... end`, or add the following right after the `select` statement:

```
   v_mapcount       := COALESCE (v_mapcount, 0);
   v_compcount      := COALESCE (v_compcount, 0);
   v_qa_comp_date   := COALESCE (v_qa_comp_date, 0);
```

Coalesce returns the first value if it is not null, otherwise it returns the second value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nvl()` function

e.g:  `nvl(sum(total),0)`